# Watch dog starts stuttering and lagging after running for a while

Tags: watch-dogs

As what title says, I can run the game smoothly for about 10 minutes, then it starts stuttering and switching to 5-10 fps randomly. I have the second update patched but that didn't help, and lowering the setting did not help either.

The game runs on my gaming laptop: 
CPU: I7-4700MQ @ 2.40GHz
RAM: 8GB
GPU: GTX765M

Comment: What OS are you running?  8GBs seems awfully low, especially since Watch Dogs will eat 75% of that.

Comment: I'm running it on windows 7

Comment: That might explain a bit, as I'm pretty sure 2 GB isn't enough to properly run 7.  What's probably happening is massive page file swapping.

Comment: Does it help if I switch to windows 8.1?

Comment: Aren't they still doing performance patches? I thought Ultra settings for some things were still expected to cause stuttering

Comment: I only set it to medium or low, but it still shutters, I don't think it's my GPU problem, since I can run it perfectly in  first 10-20 min.

Comment: GPUs can overheat and start throttling.

Comment: I assume you meant 'stuttering' not 'shuttering'.

Comment: @user3064115 - No, it won't.  Your problem is your CPU is lacking ( its a mobile product ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the symptoms described I would assume these possible reasons:

1. CPU and/or GPU overheating with subsequent throttling. Run [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) stress test to test for issue.
2. Antivirus or other resident resident software like "keyboard switchers". Disable AV and any resident software.
3. Memory leaks in game and/or video driver, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and check that you have free memory then game starts to lag. Try to install latest graphics drivers and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to know 100% as to why this occurs. I think its some kind of memory leak after a while that builds up to a point to where the bad performance and stuttering comes into play. Many people believe that its because the engine was designed around unified memory which is whats causing the stuttering on PC with its non-unified memory. One things for sure. The new patch that was supposed to fix the issue did not. The game engine was designed around unified memory and they didn't put very much effort in making it work properly on the PC's separate ram and Vram pools.. Which is rather odd considering this game was supposed to have been designed from the ground up around the PC.